# Insertion sort, number of comparisons

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

Hi all for an assignment we must count the number of comparisons for a number of algorithms. I'm using the code in the book "Algorithms" by Sedgewick & Wayne. I don't see where my code is wrong actually... As soon we going to compare something I count my comparison...

```
public long sort(Comparable[] a) {
        if (a == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument 'array' must not be null.");
        }
        int N = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                this.comparisons++;
                if(less(a[j], a[j-1]))
                    exch(a, j, j-1);      
            }
            assert isSorted(a, 0, i);
        }
        assert isSorted(a);
        return this.comparisons;
    }
```

the less method which I use:

```
private boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
        return (v.compareTo(w) < 0);
    }
```

It must pass this test

```
Integer[] array = {4, 2, 1, 3, -1};
        Comparable[] arrayClone1 = array.clone();
        Comparable[] arrayClone2 = array.clone();
        long nbCompares1 = i.sort(arrayClone1);
        long nbCompares2 = i.sort(arrayClone2);
        System.out.println("1" + nbCompares1);
        System.out.println("2" + nbCompares2);
```

those two should be equal....

The isSorted methods:

```
 private boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a) {
        System.out.println("here");
        return isSorted(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    // is the array sorted from a[lo] to a[hi]
    private boolean isSorted(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        System.out.println("here1");
        for (int i = lo + 1; i <= hi; i++)
            if (less(a[i], a[i-1])) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Someone ideas about this? Help will be appreciated!

Comment: so what is the error you're getting again? you want your code to do insertion sort, and return the number of comparisons it has made? what is it currently doing?

Comment: No i get no error it sort perfectly but the number of comparisons isn't right ....

Comment: Post your `less` method.

Comment: how much should the number of comparisons be, and how much is your code reporting?  here is what compare to does: Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

which looks ok from your side. since you are comparing is next number is less than previous number.

Comment: I get 55 comparisons and i don't know if this is correct actually. But the test case that my prof written checks if the number of comparisons is equal with the same sorting on the same list. And in my case it's not.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out guys, just rebuild it and now it's working... Why I really don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of comparisons should be exactly N*(N-1)/2. Maybe you mess with `comparisons` field in somewhere else, so I would advise to use local variable instead:

```
public long sort(Comparable[] a) {
        if (a == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument 'array' must not be null.");
        }
        int N = a.length;
        int comparisonsCount = 0; // use this instead
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                comparisonsCount++; // edit here
                if(less(a[j], a[j-1]))
                    exch(a, j, j-1);      
            }
            assert isSorted(a, 0, i);
        }
        assert isSorted(a);
        return comparisonsCount; // and here
    }
```

Comment: Result is now different but it's still not good. But i begin to question the test method i must use.... i've updated the section...

Comment: But if you use local variable instead of field, your comparison count variables `nbCompares1` and `nbCompares2` will be equal

Comment: Yes but I still got two different values and I really don't understand hy

Comment: post your `isSorted()` method

Comment: Posted them, I also just commented out and it doesn't changed the result.

Comment: Are you sure you replaced all occurences of your `this.comparisons` with local variable?

Comment: yeah ... i made a local variable just like you said, another name just to make sure....

Comment: I also want to thanks everyone who tried to help me!